# Simple LINQ in string list

Tags: c#, linq

A little question for a simple LINQ request. This is my first time with LINQ and still not understand all mechanism.

My structure is something like this

```
List<string> baseData = new List<string>{"\"10\";\"Texte I need\";\"Texte\"",
                                         "\"50\";\"Texte I need\";\"Texte\"",
                                         "\"1000\";\"Texte I need\";\"Texte\"",
                                         "\"100\";\"Texte I need\";\"Texte\""};
```

Each line of data is construct with field separator ";" and each field are encapsule with quote ".

I have another List Compose with value i have to find in my first list. And i have the Position in line i have to search. because "Texte I need" can be equal with value i am searching

```
List<string> valueINeedToFind = new List<string>{"50","100"};
char fieldSeparator = ';';
int fieldPositionInBaseDataForSearch = 0;
int fieldPositionInBaseDataToReturn = 1;
```

I made a first Linq to extract only Line interested me.

```
List<string> linesINeedInAllData = baseData.Where(Line => valueINeedToFind.Any(Line.Split(fieldSeparator)[fieldPositionInBaseDataForSearch].Trim('"').Contains)).ToList();
```

This first request Work Great and now i have only Data Line Interested me.

My problem is I don't want all the line But only a list of the value "Texte I need" in position FieldPositionInBaseDataToReturn.

I have to made another LINQ or can i modify my first to directly get what I need?

Comment: Please provide an actual [mcve] - `new List<string>{50,100,150};` won't compile to start with... (I'd also strongly advise you to start following .NET naming conventions... local variables start with lower-case letters by convention.)

Comment: Again, a [mcve] with expected results would make it much easier to help you. At the moment I'm still finding this question pretty hard to understand. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and edit your question appropriately.

Comment: ok thank you i made modifications to my code to havent error if past into IDE.

Comment: You need to use `Select` containing the logic to extract `"Texte I need"` and then set it to the required field

Comment: You are using `Contains` for the search - that seems like a bad idea for the first field e.g. your example returns three lines.

Comment: @NetMage you are right, I already swap to Equals in my code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you will be using the split version of each line more than once, separate out the `Split` operation and then work on the resulting array:

```
List<string> linesINeedInAllData = baseData.Select(Line => Line.Split(fieldSeparator))
                                           .Where(splitLine => valueINeedToFind.Any(splitLine[fieldPositionInBaseDataForSearch].Trim('"').Contains))
                                           .Select(splitLine => splitLine[fieldPositionInBaseDataToReturn])
                                           .ToList();
```

Comment: I made some modifications by my side and my New LINQ is very similar to your answer. That's confirme my idea. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> linesINeedInAllData = baseData.Where(Line => valueINeedToFind.Any(Line.Split(fieldSeparator)[fieldPositionInBaseDataForSearch].Trim('"').Equals)).ToList()
.Select(Line => Line.Split(fieldSeparator)[fieldPositionInBaseDataToReturn].Trim('"').ToList();
```